# Why am I still using an older kernel version after upgrading?

Tags: 11.04, 11.10, upgrade, kernel

Why is the kernel still at version 2.x after upgrading from Ubuntu 11.04 to 11.10? I read that 11.10 has 3.x.

Comment: What program/utility/command are you using to check the kernel version? Also, does the newer version come up in the Update Manager after the upgrade?

Comment: i'm using uname -a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes 11.10 have version 3. Just open synaptic (I still use it) and mark version linux-image-2xx  for removal and 3xx for installation. Also install the headers for 3xx as in future you might need to compile something that needs it.

Comment: Thanx. I removed the old kernel. But also had to do grub-mkconfig. to get the boot menu updated.